# The method 'UserUpdateInfo' isn't defined for the type 'AuthService'

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I upgraded firebase_auth to ^0.18.0+1, and I am getting a few errors:

- Undefined class 'AuthException'.
- 'getCredential' is deprecated and shouldn't be used.
- FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser(): the expression doesn't evaluate to a function, so it can't be invoked.

I fixed the above but couldn't fix the below:

- The method 'UserUpdateInfo' isn't defined for the type 'AuthService'.
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'UserUpdateInfo'.

How can I resolve this? Should I just create a var and pass it in the updateInfo method?

Comment: is `AuthService` your own custom class?

Comment: Yes, it is a custom class containing signInWithApple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FirebaseAuth api has changed with version 0.18.0. https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/migration#authentication

UserUpdateInfo class has been removed in favor of named arguments and currentUser() method is no longer asynchronous.

Before:

```
          await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((val) async {
            final userUpdateInfo = UserUpdateInfo();
            userUpdateInfo.displayName =
                '${appleIdCredential.fullName.givenName} ${appleIdCredential.fullName.familyName}';
            userUpdateInfo.photoUrl = 'define an url';
            await val.updateProfile(userUpdateInfo);
          });
```

After:

```
          await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.updateProfile(
            displayName:
                '${appleIdCredential.fullName.givenName} ${appleIdCredential.fullName.familyName}',
            photoURL: 'define an url',
          );
```